# Move section to next page Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to use Crystal report for document design.
I have two subreports in main report. These both sub reports are having tables with dynamic rows coming from database.
After these subreports, main report is having few more sections.
I want to move the sections below the subreport to new page if the subreport is having more than let say x rows/records.

How can I achieve this? I have tried to use group but not able to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the **'Section Expert'** from the 'Report' Menu.

Choose the section you need to add a new page before it.
To the right there is a check box named: **'New Page Before'** and **'New Page After'**

Choose the one you need, by clicking on the button to right (**x-2 button**).

Enter the Following Formula: Count({@YourDesiredField})>*x*

Comment: I tried but it adds page break after each record, I want page break after let say 6 records. Not getting expected result may be I am doing something wrong.

Comment: try it on the footer of this group not details

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared variable in subreport or total no of records 
And in main report and place section
Now in section expert on new page after 
If remainder(recordnumber%6)=0 then true else false